# apache http client 4.3 - how to set protocol version

Tags: http, apache-httpclient-4.x

How do you set the protocol version on a CloseableHttpClient object or HttpPost object with http client 4.3 now that setParams and getParams are deprecated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/");
post.setProtocolVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
```

Comment: httpClient version 5 has `setVersion` function

Answer (score 4):

or use that builder pattern they are so fond of these days:

```
final HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.post()
    .setVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
    .setUri(requestURI)
    .addHeader(key, value)
    .... <whaterver more you want to add to the request>         
    .build()
```

Comment: Odd thing to be snide about